# Find and replace html tags using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I got the following value from `<textarea>`.

`This is example have <b>MANY</b> text $which has a div like this <div>Great</div> again it has another html tag like  <p>Poor</p> then $ we can replace <b>ALL<b> HTML tags from in between two dollar signs`

Now I want a jQuery regular expression which should process above content and give me content with HTML tags, ie. just remove HTML tags in between the two dollar signs as follows.

`This is example have <b>MANY</b> text $which has a div like this Great again it has another html tag like  Poor then $ we can replace <b>ALL<b> HTML tags from in between two dollar signs`

Thank for your great help on this.

Comment: You can't do this with jquery, but you can do this with regex. What language or regex engine are you using ?

Comment: Yes I want to do it using Regex in jQuery or Javascript may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a match to focus on the text between the dollar signs and then do the replace `'text'.match(/\$(.+)\$/)[1].replace(/(<.+?>)/g, '')`

You can do `.match(/\$(.+?)\$/)[1]` if you have several PAIRS of dollars

Comment: Thank you very much Thanos Dodd for your great help.

Comment: Super. If that answered your question, I'd appreciate if you ticked on my answer